# Should accepted answers be edited if better or new information is available?

Tags: discussion

I googled a question for PHP, how to add my own errors to the Validator, and I came across this question:

[Adding custom validation errors to Laravel form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158580/adding-custom-validation-errors-to-laravel-form)

I read all the answers, but didn't actually find what was useful for me until I read the comments of like the 5th answer down. This is because, at the time of the question, the method in that comment hadn't been implemented yet.

Considering it's still the top result and I had a lot of trouble actually finding the answer, I feel it would be useful to add a section to the accepted answer that says something like

[edit] After this answer was accepted, an [After Validation Hook](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#after-validation-hook) was implemented which provides this functionality in a more complete way.

I feel like such an edit would be valuable to future people, but I don't know if that's breaking the rules, and if it is breaking the rules, should there be reasonable exceptions? I think none of us want the internet full of outdated answers.

Comment: Write your own answer. It would need to be more than a link to something else though.

Comment: Would it not be a long term problem for stackoverflow and developers in general if outdated answers are all at the top and up to date answers are buried at the bottom of questions?

Comment: People will vote, cream will rise.

Comment: @RobertLongson That's the Utopian ideal. In practice, deprecated or plain wrong but highly upvoted answers may cause pain for people looking nowadays. Cream does not always rise, as often people will vote on the first answer helping them out, not even finding a better answer down below. It's a damn feedback loop making popular answers more popular.

Comment: @k0pernikus Adding to existing answers is also fraught, what if the new information is wrong, people will believe it to be true because the answer has a lot of upvotes from when it was correct.

Comment: @RobertLongson I am not saying that editing is the right way. Stackoverflow is painfully missing a flag for: "This answer is deprecated" feature. Or even a: "This answer may be totally wrong flag". Currently, these information may be hiding in the comments. If you are lucky and check for them.

Answer (score 2):

Current policy says no. Edits should not be made as an attempt to reply or change the intent of the answer. Rather create a new answer. You can link to other / your new answer in a comment of the highly voted one to steer people away from it.

Do I think they should be edited? Yes, but only to prominently link to better / new answers. You should not change the existing content. (Somebody might be running an outdated version and the answer may still apply for them.)

It's how I handled [my own highly up-voted but not so great anymore answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966740/how-to-host-google-web-fonts-on-my-own-server/13197808#13197808) pointing people to better answers.

Keep in mind that this is currently only feasible with your own answers, as edits to other's people answers would get rejected due to "Attempt to reply" or "Should be comment" by the current policy.

I am arguing for the policy to change though.